# Fabric (Twitter) Do not download pictures of tweet

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, twitter

I use simple code
https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html

I need view Twitter post in Google Maps markers info.

call in

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter 
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

  final View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mapview, null);
  final CompactTweetView TW = (CompactTweetView)  view1.findViewById(R.id.bike_tweet);
  TW.setTweet(TWList.data.get(Integer.parseInt(SUrlVK)));
  return view1;
```

XML mapview

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:twittersdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.CompactTweetView
        android:id="@+id/bike_tweet"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        twittersdk:tw__tweet_id="638735676922556416" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Do not download pictures of tweet

The first call to the user's icon is also not loaded.

On the second call icon is displayed

screenshot
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/WToJF.png

Comment: Are there any warnings or messages in the Logcat that would give any clues?

Comment: I assume that the reason:
They offer download in example https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html
TweetUtils.loadTweets(tweetIds, new Callback<Tweet>() {
-----------
I appoint the object
TW.setTweet(.....);
---------
tweets I have, so start downloading every time, I do not want
-------------
evening check the logs

Comment: a similar problem, no solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725753/picasso-image-loading-issue-in-googlemap-infowindowadapter