# Google map Info window won't open at first click, instead it will show on second click (ANDROID JAVA)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, picasso

**I am using below code to open up an infowindow in my map:**

**//Define popup**

*private View popup=null;*

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
        if(popup == null){
            popup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_adress,null);
        }
        final ImageView customadresimage = (ImageView) popup.findViewById(R.id.customadresimage); //my imageview       
        Picasso.get().load(marker.getSnippet()).resize(200,200).into(customadresimage); //save and show photo from firebase  
        return popup;
    }
});
```

When I clicked pin, photo dont show firstly, when i clicked secondly, photo is shown.

1. First Click
   [image]
2. Second Click:
   [image]
   What is wrong ?

Comment: Yes, my bad in example source code, but description is alright. I'm add example code slightly later.

Comment: Hello. When will you share code ?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I'm a little bit busy now/ Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32741969/6950238) solution.